# Resizing canvas inside a smart object in a mockup

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject, canvas

I have alot of mockups that are to be used for mass production; running scripts and all to place designs.

So my problem is when I resize the canvas inside a smart object to fit to a frame/guide layer I have made the whole "Your design here" smart object gets ruined, it enlarges and somewhat ruins the mesh warp.

Reason for having the layer guide is all the designs are in that ratio, so when I run the scripts it fits perfectly.

[image: problem]

Comment: Why are you trying to resize the canvas inside a smart object?  Would it not be better to resize the content to fit the existing canvas?

Answer (score 2):

The point of using a Smart Object in this fashion is that you **don't** resize the canvas of the smart object.

Leave the smart object the *same size* always.. and merely replace the contents within it **without** altering the canvas size of the smart object. i.e. scale the *image* in the smart object, not the canvas.

The canvas of the Smart Object should cover your entire printable region. Therefore, it acts as a boundary for what *is possible*. Within that you adjust the *contents* to fit the *unchanging* printable region.